# Портирование jQuery-плагинов на React.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин, reactjs

Последнее время, React.js набирает огромную популярность в веб-разработке. Очень много проектов выбирают эту платформу. В процессе разработки приходит понимание того, что jQuery-плагины, встроенные в React приложение, смотрятся несколько чужеродно. Мне, как разработчику плагинов, интересна тема их портирования и у меня появилось несколько вопросов:

1. Нужно ли это вообще? Насколько react-разработчики заинтересованы в портировании огромной базы jQuery-плагинов на свою платформу?
2. Насколько стабилен React.js на текущий момент, планируются ли в ближайшем будущем существенные изменения его концепции?
3. Имеет ли смысл создание изолированных react-плагинов в отрыве от конечного проекта, и возможно ли это вообще?
4. Существуют ли какие-то паттерны, регламентирующие создание плагинов на react.js (подобные тем, что существуют для jQuery)? И есть ли где-то подробные гайды по созданию таких компонентов?
5. Есть ли какие-либо примеры рабочих react-плагинов?

Answer (score 3):

> Насколько react-разработчики заинтересованы в портировании огромной базы jQuery-плагинов на свою платформу?

Выберете плагин, с которого вы бы начали и посмотрите в Google AdWords, нужен ли он кому-нибудь кроме Вас

> Насколько стабилен React.js на текущий момент, планируются ли в ближайшем будущем существенные изменения его концепции?

Этот вопрос лучше задать на Github Issues

> Имеет ли смысл создание изолированных react-плагинов в отрыве от конечного проекта, и возможно ли это вообще?

https://react.parts/web существует, значит это и имеет смысл и возможно

> Существуют ли какие-то паттерны, регламентирующие создание плагинов на react.js (подобные тем, что существуют для jQuery)?

[React.js Component Guideline](https://gist.github.com/zbyte64/16f936d39e6562dfa663)

> Есть ли какие-либо примеры рабочих react-плагинов?

https://react.parts/web

P.S. Про существование React.js узнал из Вашего вопроса

Comment: В целом, это всё и так понятно, но хотелось бы услышать комментарии именно от react-разработчиков.